# How to order list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python

I have list of dictionaries as follows:

```
[
  {'id': 16419, 'name': 'Audi'},
  {'id': 13, 'name': 'BMW'},
  {'id': 31, 'name': 'Honda'},
  {'id': 50060, 'name': 'KTM'},
  {'id': 54, 'name': 'Opel'},
  {'id': 55, 'name': 'Peugeot'},
  {'id': 50083, 'name': 'PGO'},
  {'id': 16350, 'name': 'Skoda'},
  {'id': 68, 'name': 'Suzuki'},
  {'id': 2120, 'name': 'Triumph'},
  {'id': 16328, 'name': 'Others'},
  {'id': 16396, 'name': 'Seat'},
  {'id': 14979, 'name': 'Opel'},
  {'id': 6, 'name': 'Volkswagen'}
]
```

What I want to do is to order it. And I want that some dictionaries with some name values show in the beginning of the list.

I want that for example `Volkswagen`, `Audi`, `BMW`, `Opel`, `Peugeot` as first params appears in list.

Thus the wanted result should be something like this:

```
[
  {'id': 6, 'name': 'Volkswagen'}
  {'id': 16419, 'name': 'Audi'},
  {'id': 13, 'name': 'BMW'},
  {'id': 54, 'name': 'Opel'},
  {'id': 55, 'name': 'Peugeot'},
  {'id': 31, 'name': 'Honda'},
  {'id': 50060, 'name': 'KTM'},
  {'id': 50083, 'name': 'PGO'},
  {'id': 16350, 'name': 'Skoda'},
  {'id': 68, 'name': 'Suzuki'},
  {'id': 2120, 'name': 'Triumph'},
  {'id': 16328, 'name': 'Others'},
  {'id': 16396, 'name': 'Seat'},
  {'id': 14979, 'name': 'Opel'},
]
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Your sorting criterion is not well defined. Does Volkswagen come before Audi or is the order within the brands you named irrelevant? What about the order outside of the named brands?

Comment: @timgeb I want to add some more used car makes at the beginning of the list. Thus I want that Volkswagen comes at first place, Audi second, BMW third..

Comment: @timgeb Check the answer. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an appropriate key function for your sorting. This one orders by the given names first (in the given order). All other brands come after that with no order specified among themselves:

```
>>> rank = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(['Volkswagen', 'Audi', 'BMW', 'Opel', 'Peugeot'])}
# {'Volkswagen': 0, 'Audi': 1, ...}
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: rank.get(x['name'], len(rank)))
[{'id': 6, 'name': 'Volkswagen'},
 {'id': 16419, 'name': 'Audi'},
 {'id': 13, 'name': 'BMW'},
 {'id': 54, 'name': 'Opel'},
 {'id': 14979, 'name': 'Opel'},
 {'id': 55, 'name': 'Peugeot'},
 {'id': 31, 'name': 'Honda'},
 {'id': 50060, 'name': 'KTM'},
 {'id': 50083, 'name': 'PGO'},
 {'id': 16350, 'name': 'Skoda'},
 {'id': 68, 'name': 'Suzuki'},
 {'id': 2120, 'name': 'Triumph'},
 {'id': 16328, 'name': 'Others'},
 {'id': 16396, 'name': 'Seat'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to define a custom sorting order.

```
dicts = [
  {'id': 16419, 'name': 'Audi'},
  {'id': 13, 'name': 'BMW'},
  {'id': 31, 'name': 'Honda'},
  {'id': 50060, 'name': 'KTM'},
  {'id': 54, 'name': 'Opel'},
  {'id': 55, 'name': 'Peugeot'},
  {'id': 50083, 'name': 'PGO'},
  {'id': 16350, 'name': 'Skoda'},
  {'id': 68, 'name': 'Suzuki'},
  {'id': 2120, 'name': 'Triumph'},
  {'id': 16328, 'name': 'Others'},
  {'id': 16396, 'name': 'Seat'},
  {'id': 14979, 'name': 'Opel'},
  {'id': 6, 'name': 'Volkswagen'}
]

brand_order = ['Volkswagen', 'Audi', 'BMW', 'Opel', 'Peugeot']
order = dict(zip(brand_order, range(len(brand_order))))

dicts_sorted = sorted(dicts, key=lambda d: order.get(d['name'], float('inf')))
print(dicts_sorted)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 6, 'name': 'Volkswagen'}, 
 {'id': 16419, 'name': 'Audi'}, 
 {'id': 13, 'name': 'BMW'},
 {'id': 54, 'name': 'Opel'},
 {'id': 14979, 'name': 'Opel'},
 {'id': 55, 'name': 'Peugeot'},
 {'id': 31, 'name': 'Honda'},
 {'id': 50060, 'name': 'KTM'},
 {'id': 50083, 'name': 'PGO'},
 {'id': 16350, 'name': 'Skoda'},
 {'id': 68, 'name': 'Suzuki'},
 {'id': 2120, 'name': 'Triumph'},
 {'id': 16328, 'name': 'Others'},
 {'id': 16396, 'name': 'Seat'}]
```

Falling back to `float('inf')` ensures that whatever is not in `order` comes last.